# Injecting Template text as html element in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking for a solution where I have a line something this

```
This line have {{input}} in it and also the {{select}} in it.
```

Now this line is coming from database from backend and my frontend is Vue JS 2.6

What I want to achieve is I want to parse the {{input}} and convert it into html input tag like

```
<input type="text" class="some-class">
```

and same for the {{select}}

```
<select> <option value="Option value">Option Content</option> </select>
```

I am not sure how I inject it in the vue I am using vue with vuex

Please guide my, Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try using `v-html` directive of vue. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: I tried it but it's not supporting other vue events and props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got that right, but you now have a template string that you need to use in your component. You can try to turn the template string into a component and then use it in the parent component.

```
Vue.component('my-input', {
  template: '<input type="text" class="some-class">'
})
```

```
<div id="parent-demo">
  <my-input></my-input>
</div>
```

---

If you only have a `{{input}}` string and need to convert it to a component, you can write your own conversion function to convert `{{input}}` to a template string(`<input type="text" class="some-class">`), and then create the component in the same way as above

Comment: I am such a fool, I am really a fool, Thank you so much mate.